# Como convierto la posición de C_Long a int en Python?

Tags: python

estoy haciendo una clase con varias funciones entre ellas conseguir la posición del mouse en una ventana de sdl2 (pysdl2) y tengo que convertirla de C_long a int como lo hago?

```
import sdl2 #PySDL2
import ctypes

    def get_mouse(self):
        x, y = ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0)
        sdl2.mouse.SDL_GetMouseState(ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.byref(y))
        return x,y
```

Comment: Hee....`int(tu_variable)`? Aunque no conozco bien el modulo y no sé si eso funcione

Comment: No eso no funciona ya lo probé

Comment: Por eso es importante agregar lo que has intentado -_-. Si quieres puedes  leer [ask]

Comment: ya lo he resuelto solo es agregar el value de la variable

Comment: Sería bueno que pongas tu respuesta :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se debe usar el `.value`

```
def get_mouse(self):
    dx, dy = ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0)
    sdl2.mouse.SDL_GetMouseState(ctypes.byref(dx), ctypes.byref(dy))
    x,y = int(dx.value), int(dy.value)
    return x,y
```